Mariadb datadir? basedir?
So I am having trouble understanding what datadir and basedir is. I need to do a docker network with mariadb, nginx and wordpress. but the only problem I have currently is that I dont know what the datadir and basedir is. help would be appreciated
This is my docker-compose.yml
networks:
  inception:
    driver: bridge

# secrets:
#   mariadb-pw:

services:
  nginx:
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: ./requirements/nginx
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./srcs/wordpress:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - inception
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress
    build:
      context: ./requirements/wordpress
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./srcs/wordpress:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - inception
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      mariadb:
        condition: service_healthy
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    build:
      context: ./requirements/mariadb
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./srcs/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "healthcheck.sh", "--connect", "--innodb_initialized"]
      start_period: 10s
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      - inception
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: always

This is my dockerfile for mariadb:
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt install mariadb-server -y

COPY ./conf/50.server.cnf /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
COPY ./tools/install.sh ./install.sh
RUN chmod +x install.sh

RUN mkdir -p /run/mysqld
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /run/mysqld
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql

EXPOSE 3306

CMD [ "./install.sh" ]

And this is my install.sh:
#!/bin/bash

service mysql start

mysql_install_db --initialize --user=root --user=$MARIADB_USER --datadir=? --basedir=?

echo "Creating user and db..."
cat << EOF > /etc/mysql/init.sql
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $MARIADB_DATABASE;
    CREATE USER '$MARIADB_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$MARIADB_PASSWORD';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $MARIADB_DATABASE.* TO '$MARIADB_USER'@'%';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EOF
mysql < /etc/mysql/init.sql

echo "Database and user successfully created."

kill $(cat /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid)

exec mysqld


For the datadir I tried: /opt/mysql/mysql/data, or /var/lib/mysql
and for the basedir I tried: /opt/mysql/mysql/, or /usr/local but both are not working
my 50.server.cnf:
[server]

[mysqld]

user                    = root
pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
basedir                 = /usr
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                  = /tmp
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

[mariadb]

[mariadb-10.5]

This is the error I get every time:
Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!

FATAL ERROR: Could not find my_print_defaults

The following directories were searched:

    /opt/mysql/mysql/bin
    /opt/mysql/mysql/extra

If you compiled from source, you need to either run 'make install' to
copy the software into the correct location ready for operation.
If you don't want to do a full install, you can use the --srcdir
option to only install the mysql database and privilege tables.

If you are using a binary release, you must either be at the top
level of the extracted archive, or pass the --basedir option
pointing to that location.

The latest information about mysql_install_db is available at
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-system-tables-mysql_install_db
Creating user and db...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
Database and user successfully created.
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: No such file or directory
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
2024-11-24 18:58:25 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.3.39-MariaDB-0+deb10u2 source revision ca001cf2048f0152689e1895e2dc15486dd0b1af as process 1
2024-11-24 18:58:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2024-11-24 18:58:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2024-11-24 18:58:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-11-24 18:58:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-11-24 18:58:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-11-24 18:58:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2024-11-24 18:58:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2024-11-24 18:58:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-11-24 18:58:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2024-11-24 18:58:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=48579
2024-11-24 18:58:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 13 pages from redo log.
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.39 started; log sequence number 1601327; transaction id 8
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Cannot open '/var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2024-11-24 18:58:26 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist


Why aren't you using the official mariadb container image (which would greatly simplify your use of mariadb in a container environment)?

What does your ./conf/50.server.cnf file look like?

Please edit your question when people ask for additional information; trying to paste code and configuration in a comment doesn't allow for proper formatting and is often illegible.

I needed to install mariadb that way. enforced by university

That doesn't make any sense. The official MariaDB images and debian:buster both come from the same registry


For the datadir I tried: /opt/mysql/mysql/data, or /var/lib/mysql and for the basedir I tried: /opt/mysql/mysql/, or /usr/local but both are not working

Looking at the official image as an example, it looks like datadir should be /var/lib/mysql (since that's what you're setting up in your install.sh script), and basedir should be /usr:
root@8d092a06308f:/etc/mysql# grep -E '(base|data)dir' mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
basedir                 = /usr
#datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql

But while looking into that question, I noticed a number of other issues with your install.sh script:

While looking for documentation on mysql_install_db, I discovered that it does not take --initialize option, and in fact when running it as part of tools.sh you see the message:
[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--initialize'


You are conflating MARIADB_USER (which is a user you create in the mariadb grant tables) with the value passed to the --user option to mysql_init_db, which is the user id under which mariadb will be running. The value of --user should be mysql, based on the permissions you're setting up in your Dockerfile.

You are calling service mysql start at the beginning of install.sh, but this is unnecessary and problematic: you are starting the database daemon yourself with the terminal exec mysqld in the script, and starting the (unconfigured) service prevents mysql_install_db from running properly since the running service has already acquired locks on files in the datadir.

After calling mysql_install_db, you need to stall a temporary database server in order to successfully execute your init.sql script (and then stop the temporary server). Again, you can look at the official image for a more robust example of how to do this, but I've included an example below.


If we update install.sh to correct all the above issues, we end up with something like this:
#!/bin/bash

chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --basedir=/usr

echo "Starting temporary server"
mysqld --skip-networking --default-time-zone=SYSTEM --socket="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock" --wsrep_on=OFF \
        --expire-logs-days=0 \
        --skip-slave-start \
        --loose-innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=0 \
        --skip-ssl &
mariadb_pid=$!

echo "Waiting for database startup"
while :; do
  echo -n '.'
  if mysql --database=mysql --skip-ssl <<<'SELECT 1' &> /dev/null; then
    break
  fi
  sleep 1
done
echo

echo "Creating user and db..."
cat << EOF > /etc/mysql/init.sql
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $MARIADB_DATABASE;
    CREATE USER '$MARIADB_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$MARIADB_PASSWORD';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $MARIADB_DATABASE.* TO '$MARIADB_USER'@'%';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EOF
mysql < /etc/mysql/init.sql

echo "Database and user successfully created."
echo "Stopping temporary server"
kill $mariadb_pid
wait $mariadb_pid

echo "Starting persistent server"
exec mysqld

You will also want to update conf/50.server.cnf to run mysqld as the mysql user:
[server]

[mysqld]
user                    = mysql
pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
basedir                 = /usr
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                  = /tmp
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

[mariadb]

[mariadb-10.5]

With these changes, running a container from the image looks like this:
$ docker run --rm --name dbtest -e MARIADB_USER=example -e MARIADB_DATABASE=example -e MARIADB_PASSWORD=secret dbtest
Installing MariaDB/MySQL system tables in '/var/lib/mysql' ...
OK

.
.
.

Starting temporary server
Waiting for database startup
.
.
.
Version: '10.3.39-MariaDB-0+deb10u2'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  Debian 10
Creating user and db...
Database and user successfully created.
Stopping temporary server
Starting persistent server
.
.
.
Version: '10.3.39-MariaDB-0+deb10u2'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Debian 10

And now the server is successfully running and we can connect to the database using the supplied credentials:
$ docker exec -it dbtest mysql -uexample -psecret example
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 12
Server version: 10.3.39-MariaDB-0+deb10u2 Debian 10

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [example]>



I need to do it via bind mount, and when using a bind mount, it doesn't work again.

That sounds like you've got a basic permissions problem. When you bind mount a directory, it will have the same user id, group id, and permissions inside the container as it does outside the container. That means that if the local directory is owned by you, the mysql user in the container will probably be unable to write to it (because the mysql user will probably have a different uid). You perform a chown in your Dockerfile, but you don't do that in your install.sh. You could get things working by updating your install.sh like this:
#!/bin/bash

chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql

mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --basedir=/usr

That will work (make sure you start with an empty srcs/mariadb directory), but it's not a great solution, because now there are files in your local directory that you can't delete. A better solution is to use a docker volume for the database backing store, because that isolates the data from your user account. Using a volume would look like this:
volumes:
  mariadb_data:

services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "healthcheck.sh", "--connect", "--innodb_initialized"]
      start_period: 10s
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    environment:
      MARIADB_USER: example
      MARIADB_DATABASE: example
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: secret
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - mariadb_data:/var/lib/mysql

You would still need the chown in your install.sh.

You can find all the files referenced in this answer here.

thanks but why did you remove the volumes out of the compose. I need to do it via bind mount. and when using a bind mount, it doesn't work again.

I simplified the compose.yaml file because I wasn't interested in running either nginx or wordpress, and there were already a number of problems in your install.sh that were unrelated to filesystem permissions. See my update to the answer for how to resolve the permission problems you're seeing.
